# Ruby Float#round behaviour change after update

Tags: ruby, floating-point, upgrade, compatibility

I am upgrading a repository from Ruby version 2.3.3 to 2.5.1. A test is failing, and I have narrowed down the cause to the following behaviour:

`In version 2.3.3
1.34875.round(4)
=> 1.3487`

`In version 2.5.1
1.34875.round(4)
=> 1.3488`

Now, I'm aware of [this change](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12958), but I don't think it's relevant because a) the default behaviour was left alone, and b) the observed change is opposite to the proposed change in the default. I'm also aware that floating point numbers are not a good way to accurately store finite decimals, and that some change in precision might explain why this change has occurred. But I don't know, and I don't know how to find out.

Comment: your first example looks truncated and not rounded...

Comment: @Anthony Nevertheless, that's the result you get in 2.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you're describing sounds like https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13138, which was considered a bugfix and backported to 2.3.5. (I haven't confirmed which 2.4.x it was backported to, if any, but it was in trunk before 2.5.0.)

As you surmised, it is a precision issue. 1.34875's float representation is slightly less than 1.34875, so 2.3.3 does the overly-technically-correct thing and rounds down; newer versions recognise that rounding up is more consistent given that the float actually represents a range of values [including 1.34875].

Comment: This seems reasonable to me - I also regard it as a bugfix. I would like to redefine round to replicate the old behaviour, so that I can see whether my test failures are due to this particular change or to another one that I need to investigate. Can you think of a way to do that? (I don't really know how to read the link you've provided)

Comment: Nope, it seems too low level to be able to override effectively (short of entirely reimplementing rounding in ruby-land, which seems.. not fun). I'd suggest changing your test on 2.3.3 so that it ends up using a different value (which gets rounded "normally" in both versions); if that revised test then still passes after the upgrade, that'd be good enough for me.

Comment: You _could_ also compile a custom ruby build with https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/2dfde7e8586cf35318b6053410dba74fe9f06f8d reverted... but that seems more likely to introduce uncertainty than eliminate it, IMO.

Comment: Fair enough, many of them are automatically generated, and are sufficiently hard to test that we do a lot of long direct string-comparison (I know this is a bad thing). I've defined a round method which calls super and puts out "#{foo} rounds to #{bar}", so that if I see a change and agree with the rounding I can ignore the failure and check the other ones. Not perfect, but manageable. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Along those lines, I guess you could define a constant hash table to override certain floats and their roundings: you don't have to algorithmically reproduce the old behaviour, just force it for the specific numbers you're encountering.

Comment: Yeah, that would work too. I think it's similar effort either way

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior was not "left alone" as you suggest. There's new strategy to round to nearest even number: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/8d7c380216809ba5bd4a3eec41d7dda61f825ffa/NEWS#core-classes-updates-outstanding-ones-only (search for round).

You can use

```
> 1.34875.round(4, half: :down)
=> 1.3487
```

To preserve what seems to be the behavior in 2.3.3.

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0/NEWS#core-classes-updates-outstanding-ones-only is more relevant here; the default was changed after that commit and before the release (as discussed in the bug linked in the question). The released behaviour is, and has always been, `half: :up`.

Comment: I don't think that's true. If you call 0.5.round,1.5.round, 2.5.round and so on (in 2.3.3 and in 2.5.1) you get 1,2,3,... rather than 0,2,2,... as it would be if the default behaviour changed. Indeed, I'm pretty sure the change you reference is the one that was reverted in the link in the OP.

Comment: @matthewd are you 100% positive? I remember reading an article about why rounding to even gives more uniform roundings or sth. And was pretty sure that was a behavior in ruby at some point...